# WebApplicationInitializer not detected in Weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0, weblogic12c

I've just upgraded from weblogic 12.1.2 -> 12.1.3 and I am having problems to get de application working.

I have detected where the problem is, and I am not sure if it is a problem of misconfiguration or if it is a bug in weblogic 12.1.3 (in 12.1.2 it works perfectly).

In `spring-web-3.2.1.SNAPSHOT` there is the class:

```
@HandlesTypes(WebApplicationInitializer.class)
public class SpringServletContainerInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer {

    public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> webAppInitializerClasses, ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {

        List<WebApplicationInitializer> initializers = new LinkedList<WebApplicationInitializer>();

        if (webAppInitializerClasses != null) {
            for (Class<?> waiClass : webAppInitializerClasses) {
                // Be defensive: Some servlet containers provide us with invalid classes,
                // no matter what @HandlesTypes says...
                if (!waiClass.isInterface() && !Modifier.isAbstract(waiClass.getModifiers()) &&
                    WebApplicationInitializer.class.isAssignableFrom(waiClass)) {
                    try {
                        initializers.add((WebApplicationInitializer) waiClass.newInstance());
                    } catch (Throwable ex) {
                        throw new ServletException("Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (initializers.isEmpty()) {
            servletContext.log("No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath");
            return;
        }

        AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(initializers);
        servletContext.log("Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: " + initializers);

        for (WebApplicationInitializer initializer : initializers) {
            initializer.onStartup(servletContext);
        }
    }
}
```

We can see that if the class which implements `WebApplicationInitializer` is abstract, that class will be ignored, and its method `onStartup` won't be called.

In the web application I have this classes:

```
@Order(1)
public class SecurityApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer

@Order(2)
public class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
```

The `SpringServletContainerInitializer` receives this two classes, but what it receives are the abstract classes `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` and `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`. That's why the application is not initialized. It seems that the problem is the classes that weblogic scans while looking for `WebApplicationInitializer`. In 12.1.2, the same method (and same application) receives 6 classes, 4 of them are abstract (they belong to spring) and 2 of then are my own clases.

I have considered to use a web.xml to avoid the problem, but I would like to solve it. Any solution? Thanks!

I don't know if it's been a good idea to upgrade. First day, first problem. What could I discover next months?

Comment: I have found a solution, and it's been more easy that I thought. Finally what I've done is to force to `SecurityApplicationInitializer` and `ApplicationInitializer` to implement `WebApplicationInitializer`

Comment: Seems to be a bug in weblogic https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2465 how did you get around the problem, when I add implements
        WebApplicationInitializer to the AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer class I end up with the error ServletContext must not be null